# upload failed in play store using Android App Bundles

Tags: android

**so i recently upgraded to android studio 3.2 version and selected generate signed Android App Bundles then i created new key and password and when i upload aab file to play store it give me this error**

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). 
Error from apksigner: 
ERROR: JAR_SIG_ZIP_ENTRY_DIGEST_DID_NOT_VERIFY: SHA-1 digest of 
res/raw/video.3gp does not match the digest specified 
in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Expected: <81+dUenIZAU8PEJoHoSPp0xjcDs=>, actual: 
<0Bk3IzQH3AHiLouO4YRny7v14ac=>
```

Comment: Is it by any chance being opened by another application at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Generate signed APK and,

- Invalidate Caches
- increase versionCode

If error still happen again => retry again

for me, i retried around 10 times.

This is Android Studio's issue